# Different Alternate Representations of Functions

Tags: analysis, functions, fourier-analysis, taylor-expansion, real-numbers

Could someone please point out a source with detailed steps / other pointers for different alternate representations of functions?

For example, I know of two such ways

## 1) Taylor Series Expansion

## 2) Fourier Transform

Any suggestions for other such methods would be highly appreciated. Please note, I am looking to solve the problem from the linked question below and hence looking to see if any such alternate representation of functions could be helpful towards the simplification of the below.

Origin of Question:

[Simplifying Multiple Integral for Compound Probability Density Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862990/simplifying-multiple-integral-for-compound-probability-density-function)

Comment: I'll give you some names, you can search for the sources & see whether they're of any use to you: Lambert series; Puiseux series; Laurent series; $q$-series; Dirichlet series.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your suggestions. I will check them out.  The linked question is the reason why I am exploring these alternate representations of functions. If you have any suggestions for that, please let me know.